# Appending select options via JQuery and Ajax Chrome Issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, select

i am using Jquery and Ajax in order to populate new options to a select box. I use focus in order to capture both mouse click as well as 'tab' keyboard selection. Everything works smoothly. I have tested code in FF and chrome and the second browser seem to hide the new options and shows them only if clicked twice.

Code looks like that:

```
//select licensee
$("#licensee_id").focus(function () {
    var customer_data = $("#customer_data").val();

    var pickup_date = $("#pickup_date").val();
    var pickup_hour = $("#pickup_hour").val();
    var pickup_minute = $("#pickup_minute").val();

    var dropoff_date = $("#dropoff_date").val();
    var dropoff_hour = $("#dropoff_hour").val();
    var dropoff_minute = $("#dropoff_minute").val();

    var pickup_location_id = $("#pickup_location_id").val();
    var dropoff_location_id = $("#dropoff_location_id").val();

    var deliver_model_code = $("#deliver_model_code").val();

    if( !customer_data || !pickup_date || !pickup_hour || !pickup_minute || !dropoff_date || !dropoff_hour || !dropoff_minute || !pickup_location_id || !dropoff_location_id || !deliver_model_code )
    {
        $("#licensee_error").html('<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> Please fill-in all the required order details</div>');
    }
    else
    {
        $("#licensee_error").html('');
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: 'find-licensee.php',
            type: 'GET', 
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
            dataType: 'json', 
            data: 
            {
                customer_data: customer_data, 
                pickup_date: pickup_date, 
                pickup_hour: pickup_hour, 
                pickup_minute: pickup_minute, 
                dropoff_date: dropoff_date, 
                dropoff_hour: dropoff_hour, 
                dropoff_minute: dropoff_minute, 
                pickup_location_id: pickup_location_id, 
                dropoff_location_id: dropoff_location_id, 
                deliver_model_code: deliver_model_code
            }, 
            success:function(data) 
            {

                $('#licensee_id').empty();
                //$('#licensee_id').append($('<option>').text("Select..."));
                $("<option></option>", {value: "", text: "Select..."}).appendTo('#licensee_id');
                $.each(data, function(i, obj)
                {
                    //$('#licensee_id').append($('<option>').text(obj.name).attr('value', obj.id));
                    $("<option></option>", {value: obj.id, text: obj.name}).appendTo('#licensee_id');
                });

                //$('#licensee_id').attr('size', value);

            }
        });
    }
});
//select licensee
```

Json Array looks like that:

```
[{"name":"INTERNETi2","id":"8"},{"name":"INTERNETi","id":"7"}]
```

Firefox Result:

[image]

Chrome Result:

[image]

On second click everything looks fine...
Is there any way to fix this?

Any help will be appreciated, I tried everything but I got 0 success...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I tried my best. Is there something not clear enouch so i can explain better? I did not post the complete code to save potential readers' time. Should i?

Comment: Need enough code for us to reproduce the problem. A live demo would also be helpful

Comment: is there any notification on console of chrome

Comment: Updated my question with complete code. Console Returns results in Json array. Found out that focus event is the problem in Chrome. No workaround yet